# How to start/stop bittorrent software based on machine start up?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bittorrent

My machine is Windows XP. I am using Bit-torrent 7.7.3. I have started using bit-torrent in some days before. I am searching setting for starting Bit-torrent software on machine start up. But not getting the setting.

How to start/stop torrent software based on machine start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences-> General 
Check the box for "Start BitTorrent when Windows starts"

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop any software's icon into the "autostart" menu entry of the start menu.

When you shutdown your system the client will of course get closed automatically.